# Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declared too little query method parameters

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity:

```
@Document(collection = "userData")
@Data
public class UserData {

    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    private String id;

    @Field("orderColumns")
    private List<String> orderColumns;

    @Field("ownerId")
    private String ownerId;
}
```

And I have a repository:

```
@Repository
interface UserDataRepository extends MongoRepository<UserData, String> {
    Optional<UserData> findByOwnerIdAndOrderColumnsExists(String ownerId);
}
```

When I execute this method, I get an exception:

```
Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declared too little query method parameters!
```

Comment: Remove the `And` from your method name.

Comment: @ M. Deinum I think, you are messed up. order is a part of `orderColumns` field. It is not Order as sorting `No property ownerIdOrderColumns found for type UserData!`

Comment: You are right, my bad...

Comment: You need to add boolean method parameter for OrderColumnsExists query to work as it can have either true or false value. or you can change method name to ```findByOwnerIdAndOrderColumnsExistsTrue``` if you want to pass true in query always.

Comment: @ Harshit Unfortunally `findFirstByOwnerIdAndOrderColumnsExistsTrue ` doesn't work.